# LinkedHashSet as a returning type of API public method

Tags: java, oop, collections

Let's consider the following example.

Writing API which has public method which returns Collection of unique Objects.
I believe that is is good to write return type of that method `Set` to show to user that the items are unique. 
In case when these items are unique and ordered is it a right idea to write return type `LinkedHashSet` or it is good to be `Collection`?

I know collections which are unique and sorted. I what to know it is a good idea to set public method's return type class(TreeSet,SortedSet,LinkedHashSet). In in terms of oop.

Comment: Ordered or sorted? Ordered, you're probably best off with a `List`.

Comment: Because I cannot imagine why it would matter it is hard to answer but another alternative is to return a Set and write in the javadoc that it is ordered. The caller wouldn't typically care, would he? It is the same interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend against returning `LinkedHashSet` (unless you have a very good justification for it). If you return `Set`, you can change the `Set` implementation as you see fit, e.g. `HashSet`, `TreeSet` etc

In this case, I think your suggestion of returning `Set` is a good one as it does indicate that the items are unique. This also indicates that `contains` will generally be fast (O(1) or O(log n)).

On the other hand, `Collection` is very generic, but all it tells the caller is that it is a plain old group of somethings without any special constraints on ordering or uniqueness. Specifying `Set` means that there isn't any confusion about uniqueness, and you can use it anywhere where a `Collection` can be used anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You can return `SortedSet` - it means the items are sorted, and are unique.

You can also use `SetUniqueList` (from commons-collection) and return `List` (indicating in the javadoc that the elements are unique), or any set and return `Set` (and indicate the ordered property in javadoc)

`LinkedHashSet` retains the insertion order, but since your object is likely doing the inserts, it means nothing to the client.

Comment: Thank you for SetUniqueList , good type, but it does not answers my question.

Comment: It was a suggestion. The rest answers your question - that LinkedHashSet doesn't mean anything to the client.

Answer (score 5):

If you're items are unique then I would return a Set. Then include in the Javadoc for the method that the items are guaranteed to be in sorted order.

Comment: Meh, I like @Bozho's answer better, actually!

Comment: +1. I think your answer is much better than Bozho's, in that it actually answers the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you should ask yourself: **"What is the most generic type that specifies the characteristcs of what this method returns?"**

If the characteristic of the method is to return a a handful of *unique* objects, *sorted* in some way, then the most generic standard class that represents this is `SortedSet`.

If you return a `TreeSet`, then the method is giving details on the implementation of what it returns (ie, TreeSet is a concrete class, not an interface), which often you want to avoid in OOP.

If you return a `Collection`, you are not stating that the objects are unique, nor that they are sorted in some way.

If you return a `LinkedHashSet`, not only you fail to state that the returned collection is somehow sorted, but you also fail in the abstraction aspect of OOP (this is a concrete class, so you are leaking implementation details; always try to return interfaces, unless you have a good reason).

Answer (score 1):

I would only give a method the return type `LinkedHashSet<...>` if it's part of the method's *contract* that its return-value is a `Set<...>` with a consistent ordering. And even then I'd be a bit wary of doing that unless it's *also* part of the method's contract that its return-value is modifiable, since otherwise `LinkedHashSet<...>` also precludes the use of `Collections.unmodifiableSet(...)`.

In most cases, I think `Set<...>` is a better return-type. Alternatively, if the consistent ordering is particularly important, then you can use `SortedSet<...>` and switch to one of the implementations of that (such as `TreeSet<...>`); that still allows `Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It you want to make it clear they are unique and are ordered purely based on the order of insertion, you could return `LinkedHashSet` However, `Set` is usually the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 21 you could return a [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html).  This would indicate that the result is both a `Set` with unique elements, and a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) with a well-defined encounter order.

This has the additional benefits involved with having method signatures defined in terms of interfaces rather than concrete classes.  For instance, by not declaring the specific implementation type returned gives latitude to future changes to the method to return a different type of collection that may make more sense to the future implementation, while still guaranteeing that be a `Set` with a well-defined ordering.